# Firefox extension that support Priority Inbox of Gmail

Tags: gmail, firefox-extensions

I have Gmail Manager installed as addon on Firefox 3.6.x. Unfortunately it seems not working very well with the new **Priority Inbox** feature of GMail.

Now the counter display me only mails that arrive in the priority inbox and not the other.

Do you known any other extensions for Firefox that works well with this new Gmail feature. It would be nice have 2 numbers, one for the mails in the Priority Inbox and one for the other new emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WebMail Notifier](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4490/) does:

> WebMail Notifier checks your webmail
>   accounts and notifies the number of
>   unread emails... Supports : gmail,
>   yahoo, hotmail, aol, daum, naver,
>   nate, paran, POP3/IMAP and more

The latest version 2.5.9 from September 8, 2010, claims:

> support priority inbox in gmail

Comment: Addon can be improved but the counter works very well, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess would be to try http://userscripts.org, but a search for Priority Inbox yields nothing useful.

So my best guess is that you will need to write an own GreaseMonkey user script... :-(